# iPad Landscape not resizing SubViews correctly

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios

I am writing an iPad application using MonoTouch, MonoDevelop and Interface Builder, and i've stumbled across a problem that I can't seem to solve. It is probably something simple. What I am trying to do is force an application to Landscapemode from start. The application starts in Landscape, but doesn't resize the subviews correctly.

Basically what I am doing in my appdelegate is that I add a SubView called IndexViewController.xib to Window. In IndexViewController I have a View with a Label on it, if I then in IndexViewController override the ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to return this: it works correctly.

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation toInterfaceOrientation)
{
            return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight));
}
```

However, I now try to create a NavigationController and add it to the IndexController.xib-view on the Initialize:

```
    void Initialize ()
    {
        this.View.AddSubview (NavController.View);
    }
```

It rotates correctly but doesn't fill the entire "window", I have posted a screenshot and a sample solution. And my **info.plist** is set to allow "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft" and "UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeftRight" as **UISupportedInterfaceOrientations**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC7ON.jpg)

[Sample solution here](http://www.zshare.net/download/86235767817d09be/)

There is probably something dead simple simple that I am missing, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this may be due to the fact the way you're building the app's hierarchy isn't the suggested way of doing so. While you could carry on this way, you'll encounter more problems down the road.
Ideally you want to be adding the NavigationController's View the window rather than the having the NavigationController contained within a UIViewController.

In the app delegate, I would do something along the lines of:

```
IndexViewController indexVC = new IndexViewController()
UINavigationController navController = new UINavigationController(indexVC);
window.AddSubview(navController.View);
```

This will add the navigation controller's view to the window, with the `RootViewController` of the `NavigationController` being your `IndexViewController`

You should also remove the `UINavigationController` that is added to your IndexViewController in `Initialise()`.

I just downloaded your sample solution and tried this very quickly and it loaded the app in Landscape with the view fully filling the screen. It didn't auto rotate, but this'll certainly be a good starting point for you :)